# How to match an integer from one collection with it's identical in another collection, creating a many to many relationship.

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-collections

This is supposed to be a simple many to many relationships in meteor but I must be missing something because i cannot get it to work.

I have a Collection called **reblog** and in it is an array of integers called `descovered` see image

[image]

I have a second collection called **posts** which is a collection of posts, and these posts have an id. take a look at the second image

[image]

I want to create a many to many relationships between the **posts** and the **reblog** collection. i.e, I want to match the integer

`descovered: 9`

from the reblog collection, with:

`id: 9`

from the **posts** collection so that I can display only the posts matched from the **reblog** collection. This of course will allow me to display the title of the post and other attributes.

This is my js

```
Template.reblogging.helpers({
descovered() {
  var id = FlowRouter.getParam('_id');

  //fetch the reblog collection contents

  var rebloged = reblog.find().fetch();

  //log below is showing that the fetch is successful because i can see the objects fetched in console

  console.log(rebloged);

  //create the relationship between the posts collection and the reblog collection

  var reblogger = posts.find({
    id: {
      $in: rebloged
    }
  }).fetch();

  //nothing is showing with the log below, so something is going wrong with the line above?

  console.log(reblogger);
  return reblogger
}
});
```

I must be missing something because this seems a pretty straightforward thing but it's not woring

And my HTML is like this

```
<template name="reblogging">
 {{#each descovered }}
<ul class="">
  <li>
    <h5 class="">{{title.rendered}}</h5>
  </li>
</ul>
{{/each}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert to strings and parse, you can use `.map()` directly on the cursor to create an array of `descovered` values. Also since you are using Blaze you can just return a cursor instead of an array. I suspect you also meant to use your FlowRouter `_id` parameter in your first `.find()`. If you didn't then there's no need to get that param in your helper.

```
Template.reblogging.helpers({
  descovered() {
    const id = FlowRouter.getParam('_id');
    const reblogArr = reblog.find(id).map(el => { return el.descovered });    
    return posts.find({ id: { $in: reblogArr } });
  }
);
```

Comment: I can't get this to work. **console.log(reblogArr);** shows nothing, @Michel

Comment: What is `reblog.find(id).count()`?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the matching was accurate, however, the data from `reblog` collection needed to be treated with REGEX to get rid of everything else apart from the values I needed, then turn them into an array, this is the final code that worked. leaving it here, Hopefully, it will help someone in the future.

```
Template.reblogging.helpers({
descovered() {
  var id = FlowRouter.getParam('_id');

  //fetch the reblog collection contents

  var rebloged = reblog.find().fetch();

  //log below is showing that the fetch is successful because i can see the objects fetched in console

  console.log(rebloged);

  //turn it into a string so i can extract only the ids
  var reblogString = JSON.stringify(rebloged).replace(/"(.*?)"/g, '').replace(/:/g, '').replace(/{/g, '').replace(/}/g, '').replace(/,,/g, ',').replace(/^\[,+/g, '').replace(/\]+$/g, '');
  //after  have extracted what i needed, i make it into an array
  var reblogArr = reblogString.split(',').map(function(item) {
    return parseInt(item, 10);
  });

  //create the relationship between the posts collection and the reblog collection

  var reblogger = posts.find({
    id: {
      $in: reblogArr
    }
  }).fetch();

  //nothing is showing with the log below, so something is going wrong with the line above?

  console.log(reblogger);
  return reblogger
}
});
```